# How to find and select fields in the Rust MongoDB driver?

Tags: mongodb, rust

How can I do the mongosh shell equivalent in the [Rust MongoDB driver](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/)?

```
db.library.find({"author": "George Orwell"}, {book: 1, _id:0})
```

That returns all the books from the queried author? (Show the book field only by "George Orwell")

The doc shows one example with the filter but I can't replicate the above with both criteria. `FindOptions` didn't seem to have anything that could be used for it.

```
use mongodb::{bson::doc, options::FindOptions};

// Query the books in the collection with a filter and an option.
let filter = doc! { "author": "George Orwell" };
let find_options = FindOptions::builder().sort(doc! { "title": 1 }).build();
let mut cursor = typed_collection.find(filter, find_options).await?;
```

I guess the command above would be similar to the following in the mongosh shell:

```
db.library.find({"author": "George Orwell"}).sort({book: 1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for the FindOptions struct](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/options/struct.FindOptions.html), there is a [projection field](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/options/struct.FindOptions.html#structfield.projection). The [FindOptionsBuilder](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/options/struct.FindOptions.html#method.builder) has a method `projection` that can set this field.

This leads me to believe you can do the following:

```
use mongodb::{bson::doc, options::FindOptions};

// Query the books in the collection with a filter and an option.
let filter = doc! { "author": "George Orwell" };
let find_options = FindOptions::builder().projection(doc! { "book": 1, "_id": 0 }).build();
let mut cursor = typed_collection.find(filter, find_options).await?;
```